# Preserve the newline character within two NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, uitextview, bing-api

In my application, I translate the content of a TextView and present it to the user.

**My Problem is:** The first string is nicely formatted with Newline Characters which got loose during the translation.

Recognized Text: [Picture 1](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4736649/2012-04-22%2017.57.48.png)
Translated Text: [Picture 2](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4736649/2012-04-22%2017.58.05.png)

**My question is:** How is it possible to somehow append the same amount of Newline Characters at the same place as in the first NSString to let it looks like the first string?

*Translation:*

```
[[MSBingTranslator sharedTranslator] initWithDelegate:self andTranslateText:txtView.text fromLan:detectedLanguage toLan:@"de"];

- (void) MSBingTranslator:(MSBingTranslator *)cls translatedText:(NSString *) text {
    txtView.text = text;
}

- (void) MSBingTranslator:(MSBingTranslator *)cls detectedLanguage:(NSString *)lan {
    detectedLanguage = lan;
}

- (void) MSBingTranslator:(MSBingTranslator *)cls failedWithError:(NSString *) error {
}
```

I'm using https://github.com/moeseth/Bing-Translator for the translation, a objective-c wrapper around Microsoft's Bing Translator.

Comment: Your code snippets seem unrelated to each other. For example, only the first makes any reference to the `myWords` variable.  Only the second makes any reference to `lb`. If you really process an array returned by `-componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` to transform each element, you can take an array of the transformed elements and recombine them into a string with `-[NSArray componentsJoinedByString:]`.

Comment: You were right, edited the question. If I do anything wrong, let me know please.

Comment: So, you separate the text by newlines and then you join the text with newlines? Why? Why don't you just pass the original text to the translator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can really do this, mainly because when you do the translation you will quite often get a different number of words than you started with.  Determining which words/groups match up with which words in the before/after strings will be really really difficult (unless you translate one word at a time which won't translate the same).  If it wasn't for this, you could just use componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet on the translated string and the go through the old array looking for the empty strings to determine where to add the new lines in the new array.

By the way, instead of creating the array and then writing it into the mutable string you can just use:

```
NSMutableString *mString = [txtView.text mutableCopy];
```

(unless you are using the array for something else)